# Different routes but using the same controller for model subclasses in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subclass, single-table-inheritance

I have a Model Property which has subclasses using STI,

and which I would like all to use the same controller with only different view partials depending on the subclass.

```
Property
Restaurant < Property
Landmark < Property
```

It works find except I'm not sure how to discern the subclass inside the controller to render the correct view.  Ie. /restaurants works and goes to the properties controller but I can't tell that they want the Restaurant subclass?

```
map.resources :restaurant, :controller => :properties
map.resources :properties
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to fi the problem would be to create a Sub-Controller:

```
class RestaurantsController < PropertiesController
end
```

In the routes you would map restaurants to the restaurants controller.

**Update:** Alternatively you could try something like this in your `routes.rb`:

```
map.resources :restaurants, :controller => :properties, :requirements => {:what => :Restaurant}
map.resources :properties, :requirements => {:what => :Property}
```

Then you can use a before filter to check params[:what] and change behaviour accordingly.

Example:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter select_model

  def select_model
    @model = params[:what].constantize
  end

  def show
    @model.find(params[:id])
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: yes, but i'd like to keep them using the same controller, with only slightly different view partials.

Comment: @holden: I've added another solution which might work for you

Comment: i tried the exact same thing, although I used :subclass instead of :what but it doesn't seem to work.  params[:what] is nil and all i get form params is "actionindexcontrollerproperties" from /restaurants ;-(

Comment: You're right. I haven't noticed this before. I haven't used this with restful routes before. I think adding a second controller is not really problematic as it's not duplicating any code, it's just one additional file with two lines in it.

Comment: Well, in my case it'll be many different files.  I just listed one submodel, but in reality there will probably be 5-6.

Comment: For resource(s) default options are passed as :requirements. I've updated the answer for you and provided an example  filter to make things more DRY