# Rails Routes - Select controller dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Lets say, for the sake of the question, that I have two user types: `type1` & `type2`. I want Rails to use a controller/module depending on the type of user that is being displayed. For example:

If `User(id: 1, type: 'type1')` has `type1` and `User(id: 2, type: 'type2')` has `type2`, going to:

```
/users/1
```

would select the Type1::UsersController. And going to:

```
/users/2
```

would select the Type2::UsersController.

This will allow me to use different controllers and views for each type.

Note: I don't want the `type` to be displayed in the URL, I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

As GoGoCarl says, this isn't really the Rails way to do things. That said, it's not that difficult to get it to work. You can do something like this in `routes.rb`:

```
get 'users/:id', to: 'type1/users#show', constraints: lambda { |request| 
  _id = request.fullpath.gsub('/users/','').to_i
  # Note: there might be an easier way to get ID from the request object
  User.find(_id)._type == 'type1'
}
get 'users/:id', to: 'type2/users#show', constraints: lambda { |request| 
  _id = request.fullpath.gsub('/users/','').to_i
  User.find(_id)._type == 'type2'
}
```

I've renamed your `type` field to `_type` in my example (because Rails uses `type` for Single Table Inheritance). I've tested this and it works as desired.

Comment: `User.find(:id)` might work (untested). This looks like a possible hack, I need to test it still. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `User.find(:id)` doesn't work: I tried it even though it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you'd be doing a lot of (probably) unnecessary fighting against the Rails way.  I would think you would want one controller as there's probably quite a bit of shared logic (such as saving, deleting, creation, etc).

To answer your question (because I hate when people leave recommendations instead of answers), then you'll need to create a Module that extends Routing, which will allow you to do custom matching.  From there, you can do your checks and route appropriately.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782407/how-can-i-route-to-different-controllers-with-the-same-url-format-in-rails).

That said, a better route to go (no pun intended) would be to have one controller which has a centralized method that can select views.

```
def find_view view_name
  "#{view_name}#{@user.type}"
end
```

So, a call to render find_view('new') would attempt to render a view named "new-type1."  You can put all your type1 user-specific logic in that view.  Same for user type2.

Again, since I would think there would be much overlap in your user code, you may want to push this find_view method to a helper class so you can call it from your views, and do things like render specific partials instead based on the user type.  That will allow for more code re-use, which is never a bad thing.

Once you get your head wrapped around having a single controller, there are a number of simple ways that you can push user-type-specific code to different avenues -- the views method explained above, you can push all your relevant code to separate helpers which are dynamically called based on the user type, and I'm sure there's more (probably better ones).  But all those have one major thing in common -- you'll be fighting Rails a LOT less, and you will have less duplicate code, if you succumb to letting Rails have its way with one route, one controller.

Good luck, hope that helps.