# What modules to include to make a selectable controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capability

I want to implement an object-capabilities system in Rails and that means having a single route dispatching on dozens of different facet objects:

```
resources :facets, param: :swissnumber
```

Implmenting this via code in the routing as suggested in [Rails Routes - Select controller dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494811/400277) seems highly impractical, so I'd prefer to use STI instead in the Facet model.

I'd have a barebones controller that would just dispatch actions to the facet:

```
def show
  Facet.find(params[:swissnumber]).show(request,params)
end
```

So in methods of the `Facet` model, I want to be able to call methods typical of controllers, like `head` or `render`. What modules can I expect to need?

For the moment, I'm chasing what modules I should include, starting with `ActionController::Head` and `ActionController::Rendering` but they're not enough and I was wondering if there's an umbrella module.

Or maybe my `Facet` should extend `ActionController::API` or `::Base` and include modules from ActiveRecord? (I'm in a multiple inheritance scenario…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was looking to replicate the syntax of a typical controller source code, but it's just methods on an implicit object, so the simple solution was to pass the controller to the facet, where I do `controller.render` or `controller.request` and so on…